# Ошибка при создании двумерного массива Python IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

```
B=[]
for n in range(0,6):
    for k in range(0,6):
        B[n][k]=n+k

print(B)
```

Выдает ошибку IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

```
B = []
for n in range(0, 6):
    tmp = []
    for k in range(0, 6):
        tmp.append(n + k)
    B.append(tmp)
```

Или так:

```
B = [[0] * 6 for i in range(6)]
for n in range(0, 6):
    for k in range(0, 6):
        B[n][k]=n + k
```

Или так:

```
B = [[n + k for k in range(6)] for n in range(6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Строка

```py
B[n][k]=n+k
```

Значит "установить `[n][k]` элементу `B` значение `n+k`", но `B` изначально пустой, поэтому попытка обращения к любому его элементу выдаст ошибку.

---

Для Вашей цели подойдёт код:

```py
B=[]
for n in range(0,6):
    B.append([])  # Добавляем(!!) в B ещё один список
    for k in range(0,6):
        B[n].append(n+k)  # Добавляем в добавленный список нужные элементы
```

Можно в одну строку:

```py
B = [[n+k for k in range(6)] for n in range(6)]
```